# SwiftSoup Parse From evaluateJavaScript

Tags: swift, macos, html-parsing, wkwebview, swiftsoup

I'm trying to use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) to parse HTML from a webpage.  I'm using `evaluateJavaScript` with `"document.getElementById(\"fieldsort\").innerHTML"` as my JavaScript.  I'm not using `String(contentsOf: URL)` because that doesn't return the HTML for the elements of the page.

I am saving the string as `str`, and I'm using `SwiftSoup.parse(str)` to parse it.  However, when I print the value of the Document that is created, it is empty.  How do I correctly parse this and is there a better, more efficient way to use SwiftSoup with a webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, parsing as XML solved it.